# Discord bot Python API guild.members

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot and need to retrieve the members from my guild(server).
But when I run this code I get a member_count equal to three (the actual number of people in my server. One of them is the bot) but when I ask to print them there's only one (the bots)

```
 @client.event
 async def on_message(message):
     if message.author == client.user:
         return

     print(message.guild.member_count)
     print(len(message.guild.members))
     print(message.guild.members)
```

Output:

```
  >>> 3
  >>> 1
  >>> <The bots info>
```

Edit: corrected output

Comment: You have to enable member intents, take a look at the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Comment: This worked. I activated the intents on the bot application page and works perfectly. Thx